# Recursion that splits a object with numbers in several data frame rows

Tags: r, recursion

I want to write a function that splits a vector with several numbers in a way which if I have the line:

```
secs = c(1, 5, 8, 19, 25, 91)
```

It'll answer me a data frame with two rows, called `st` and `end` in which each line I would have a value and the next one in the vector minus 1. For example, if I use `apply(secs, function)`, R would answer me the following:

```
|  st | end|
|  1  |  4 |
|  5  |  7 |
|  8  | 18 |
| 19  | 24 |
| 25  | 91 |
```

Note that the last value, i.e. 91 remains the same, I want that to remain the same value because its the last value. I tried to do that function via recursion, but failed to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
splitVecStEnd <- function(.x) {

  # create auxiliary dataframe
  # lead and calc "-1"
  resp <- tibble(
    st  = .x,
    end = lead(st)-1,
  )

  # force final number
  resp[nrow(resp)-1,]$end = resp[nrow(resp),]$st

  # remove last row
  resp <- resp[1:nrow(resp)-1,] 
  return(resp)

}
```

Answer (score 3):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
secs %>%
 enframe() %>%
 transmute(st = value,
           end = if_else(row_number() == n() - 1,
                         lead(value),
                         lead(value) - 1)) %>%
 slice(-n())

     st   end
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4
2     5     7
3     8    18
4    19    24
5    25    91
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data.frame(st = head(secs, -1), end = c(head(secs[-1] - 1, -1), tail(secs, 1)))
#  st end
#1  1   4
#2  5   7
#3  8  18
#4 19  24
#5 25  91
```